# Match string with numbers and forward slash in it using regex and javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match a string using regex that sometimes contains a forward slash in it it `/`.

This is an example string.
`Armor Wars #1/2`

But it could also be `Armor Wars #1` or `Armor Wars #25.2` or `Armor Wars #5.NOW` virtually anything can come after the #.

This is the code I have right now, but I can't get it grab the full `#1/2`. It will just grab `#1`

```
const message = 'Armor Wars #1/2' // Try edit me

const issueNumber = message.match(/#\w+/)[0]

// Log to console
console.log(issueNumber)
```

I've tried various other patterns, but can't figure out why it just keeps stopping at the slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/#\w+(?:[\/.]\w+)?/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ojTpNd/1).

*Details*:

- `#` -  a `#` char
- `\w+` - one or more letters, digits or underscores
- `(?:[\/.]\w+)?` - an optional sequence of

  - `[\/.]` - a `/` or `.`
  - `\w+` - one or more "word" chars

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const message = 'Armor Wars #1/2'
console.log( message.match(/#\w+(?:[\/.]\w+)?/)[0] ) // => #1/2
```

Comment: If there's any possibility of slashes being used more than once, you could use `/#[\w\/]+/`.

Comment: Or `/#\w+(?:[\/.]\w+)*/`